# Should Celery sub-processes show up on ps aux | less

Tags: celery, tornado, supervisord

I'm using Supervisord with Celery on a tornado server (note: not tcelery, since my server isn't using any async features yet) with three workers: w1, w2, and w3.  Each has a concurrency of 10.  I do this via supervisor by adding the following to /etc/supervisord.conf:

```
[program:sendgrid_gateway_server]
command=sudo python main.py -o runserver
numprocs=1
directory=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway/logs/server_log.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root

[program:sendgrid_gateway_server_w1]
command=celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
numprocs=1
directory=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway/logs/w1_log.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root

[program:sendgrid_gateway_server_w2]
command=celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
numprocs=1
directory=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway/logs/w2_log.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root

[program:sendgrid_gateway_server_w3]
command=celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
numprocs=1
directory=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/sendgrid_gateway/sendgrid-gateway/logs/w3_log.txt
autostart=true
```

The first [program] block is for my main python application that runs Tornado.  The next three are (obviously) my Celery workers.  What worries me is that when I "supervisorctl start all" all 30 processes show up in the list:

root      2547  0.0  0.0  40848  1672 ?        S    13:40   0:00 sudo python main.py -o runserver
root      2548  0.2  1.9 176140 33020 ?        Sl   13:40   0:04 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2549  0.0  2.1 196848 35632 ?        S    13:40   0:01 python main.py -o runserver
root      2560  0.2  1.9 176140 33016 ?        Sl   13:40   0:03 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2561  0.2  1.9 176140 33020 ?        Sl   13:40   0:03 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2581  0.0  1.6 175144 28616 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2582  0.0  1.6 175144 28624 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2583  0.0  1.6 175144 28628 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2584  0.0  1.6 175144 28628 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2585  0.0  1.6 175144 28628 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2586  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2587  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2589  0.0  1.6 175144 28636 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2590  0.0  1.6 175144 28644 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2591  0.0  1.6 175144 28640 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w3
root      2595  0.0  1.6 175144 28612 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2596  0.0  1.6 175144 28624 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2597  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2598  0.0  1.6 175144 28620 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2599  0.0  1.6 175144 28620 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2600  0.0  1.6 175144 28620 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2601  0.0  1.6 175144 28624 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2602  0.0  1.6 175144 28636 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2603  0.0  1.6 175144 28628 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2604  0.0  1.6 175144 28636 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2605  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2608  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2609  0.0  1.6 175144 28628 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2610  0.0  1.6 175144 28640 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2611  0.0  1.6 175144 28640 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2612  0.0  1.6 175144 28632 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2613  0.0  1.6 175144 28648 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2614  0.0  1.6 175144 28644 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w1
root      2616  0.0  1.6 175144 28640 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2
root      2617  0.0  1.6 175144 28636 ?        S    13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n w2

Those are the 30 Celery processes, plus a few extra (not quite sure why the extra ones are there...)
I was under the impression that the unnecessary processes should terminate after a task has been finished.  Is this the case or am I just loony?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they should all show as processes. However you might want to use the stopasgroup=true and killasgroup=true options under your program configurations to get stop all the child processes at once, or else they may keep running even after you have run your stop [programname] command with supervisorctl.